# How to toggle a sticky header?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below makes a sticky header which shows up once you've scrolled down 100px. How do I make the sticky header turn off once I get to a lower part of the page? Lets say 800px?

Thanks!

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100){  
    $('header').addClass("sticky");
  }

  else{
    $('header').removeClass("sticky");
  }
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100 && $(this).scrollTop() < 800) {  
        $('header').addClass("sticky");
    } else{
        $('header').removeClass("sticky");
    }
})
```

Comment: I would cache `$(this).scrollTop()` in a variable for ease of use.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could add another condition for when it the page gets to 800px:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (($(this).scrollTop() > 100) && ($(this).scrollTop() < 800)){
         $('header').addClass("sticky");
    }
    else{
         $('header').removeClass("sticky");
    }
});
```

In my example:

- `$(this).scrollTop()` is the variable representing the top of the view
- The first part of the `if statement` adds the condition for the 100px addition
- The second part of the `if statement` adds the condition for the 800px removal

Comment: I'm downvoting this answer because it is a duplicate from Gerfried's one.

Comment: @TiagoMarinho This answer includes an explanation of the parts and we answered the question at nearly the exact same time.

Comment: I disagree. From what I've saw, you answered another solution first (which was inefficient tbh) then edited it to match Gerfried's answer. Anyway, my comment was posted before you added explanation, so I'm removing my downvote.

Comment: @TiagoMarinho Thank you for your clarification. I had posted a solution, and immediately edited it to reduce its complexity. I had not yet seen the other solution, but both have the same premise as this is the simplest way to solve this problem.

Comment: sorry for the confusion then. I just hate when people answer almost the same thing to that kind of question which probably has no effort from the OP to understand what his code does or how it works. I'm probably overthinking your changes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest only to use css. If the nav is sticky, why not keep it sticky at all times, and then add margin to the main-content-holder to make room for the nav.
For example:
if the nav is 108px tall on desktop use:

```
.main-content-holder{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    margin-top:108px
}
```

then adjust height and/or position with media queries.

Comment: This may not always be the case, as the UI may be different once one has scrolled down 100px. I believe that YouTube's video manager used to work this way: the toolbar became sticky once the user scrolled past a certain point.